# Interaction of explanatory variable with time trend in a panel data fixed effects model

Tags: econometrics, fixed-effects-model, trend, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I searched but could not find another post directly addressing this.

I am interested in specifying a model where a certain policy or 'treatment' variable affects not only the the level of the dependent variable, but also its time trend. For example opening a new rail station may not only increase house price levels in the immediate vicinity, but also how quickly prices grow over time.

Can this be accommodated by including unit-specific time trend, as well as an interaction of that time trend with an explanatory variable (in addition to time and unit fixed effects, and the explanatory variable itself, as with the canonical difference-in-differences [DiD] specification with panel data)?

Comment: Welcome to CV. A unit-specific linear time trend will account for this. But why do you want to interact a time trend variable with ‘other’ covariates? What other variables are you considering?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My hypothesis would be that places with better transport accessibility see faster house price gains than those with worse accessibility. Suppose there is a policy that exogenously improves accessibility (e.g. a new rail station opened at random); I would hope the estimated coefficient on a time_trend*transport_accessibility interaction term would indicate the effect of better accessibility on the rate of change of house prices over time. This is different to it just permanently affecting their level, I think.